# oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: jboss6.x, jdbc-odbc

```
WrappedConnectionJDK6 wrapped = (WrappedConnectionJDK6) dbStrategy.getConnection();
            Connection underlyingConn = wrapped.getUnderlyingConnection();
            OracleConnection oracleConn = (OracleConnection)underlyingConn;
```

Last line gives Error -

```
> ERROR
> [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/web].[resteasy-servlet]]
> (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet resteasy-servlet
> threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot
> be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

Comment: and what is the question ?

Comment: Need to get oracle connection from WrappedConnectionJDK6 .. but its giving casting issue .. Any clue how to get oracle connection out of WrappedConnectionJDK6 ?

Comment: JBoss wraps the oracle connection  with it's own one (org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6). I am trying to  call #getUnderlyingConnection() to get the underlying connection. But while converting that into Oracle connection it is giving error... Connection Casting error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK T4CConnection should implement oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.
IMHO you have 2 driver implementation, one on the app server and one in your project dependencies, there must be a classloading issue as the retrieved driver implementation is loaded by the shared class loader and you try to cast it to a class loaded by the webApp class loader.

You can ensure that your web-app dependency is the same than the server provided implementation or just exclude the dependency from the web app when packaging it.

If you're using maven just set the scope to `provided`.

Comment: it is provided  still am facing same issue  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: ah, well honestly i don't know so. don't you have a transitive dependency somewhere ?

Comment: Actually I need to create - StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("SOMETHING", con);  but as it is from oracle utility i can not pass the connection as sql connection.. So I need to convert T4CCon to Oracle.. and the casting is giving problem..

Comment: Did you ensure server and webapp driver implementation are exactly the same ?

Comment: i have configured ojdbc6 as driver in console.. Am using JbossEAP6.. And i guess Jboss takes ironjacamar.. can that be the problem?

Comment: If you configured yourself the datasource, i suppose you provided the same lib. Maybe it can come from JCA but i don't think so. Did you have OracleDriver explicitely specified in DS configuration ? (<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>)

Comment: whatever we configure in server console.. it is showing in stanalone.xml

Comment: ie -  <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/apps" pool-name="apps" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@x</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>

Comment: Yes.. i had to remove the OJDBC6 jar.. There was no need to deploy it separately from Jboss server console.. Thanks Gab.. u had hit a bull's eye when u told "there must be a classloading issue as the retrieved driver implementation is loaded by the shared class loader and you try to cast it to a class loaded by the webApp class loader." Thanks bro.. u r life saver..