# What is the relationship between the oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection interface and the T4CConnection class?

Tags: oracle, ojdbc

I have some Java JDBC database access code that throws an exception that states in part - "[wrapping: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@477a4e1f] is not a wrapper for or implementation of oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection]".  I haven't been able to find out how `T4CConnection` and `OracleConnection` are related, if at all.  Based on the names, it seems like they should be.  How can I get an `OracleConnection` from a `T4CConnection`?

I am using Oracle 11 and 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T4CConnection` implements `OracleConnection` via the following inheritance hierarchy:
`oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection` extends `oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection` which extends `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection` which extends `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper` which implements `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection`.

The error is likely a result of a class loading problem, where the Oracle classes are being loaded from multiple jars by different class loaders.  These sources ([1](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/266722), [2](http://ravivedala.blogspot.com/2008/03/oracle-10g-passing-arrays-to-database.html), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033652/oracle-jdbc-driver-t4cconnection-cannot-be-cast-to-oracle-jdbc-oracleconnection)) discuss this in more detail.